# Nginx log: `QueryBuilder#allowEager` method is deprecated

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

```
`QueryBuilder#allowEager` method is deprecated. You should use `allowGraph` instead. `allowEager` method will be removed in 3.0
`QueryBuilder#eager` method is deprecated. You should use the `withGraphFetched` method instead. `eager` method will be removed in 3.0
QueryBuilder#omit is deprecated. This method will be removed in version 3.0
Model#$omit is deprected and will be removed in 3.0.
```

when installing Nginx on docker, logs bring this up.
any idea how i can acess the container using SSH to change those errors?